# How can consumer listen to all queues present in a channel simultaneously without knowing queue names in php rabbitmq

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I am trying to let consumer listen to all queues in nameless exchange in consumer.php but i have to mention queue names as shown:

```
$this->channel->basic_consume('Cancelcontact', '', false, false, false, false, array($this, 'processMsg'));
$this->channel->basic_consume('Acceptcontact', '', false, false, false, false, array($this, 'processMsg'));
$this->channel->basic_consume('Declinecontact', '', false, false, false, false, array($this, 'processMsg'));
```

Is there any way to get names of all queues in channel and write single basic consume for same purpose??

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is possible, it is a bad idea.

Having multiple queues allows you to have multiple consumers, each of which can handle a particular type of message. By having all of your queues go to the same consumer, your code will have to check the type of message to figure out what to do with it.

This is a duplication of the work that RabbitMQ has already done for you, and may put you in the mode of "Selective Consumer" - [an anti-pattern in RabbitMQ](http://derickbailey.com/2015/07/22/airport-baggage-claims-selective-consumers-and-rabbitmq-anti-patterns/).

The process of handling an `AcceptContact` or `CancelContact` message will be different. Therefore, the code that handles these messages will be different.

Have the code that handles `AcceptContact` messages only consume from the `AcceptContact` queue. Have the code that can handle `CancelContact` messages only consume from the `CancelContact` queue.

Comment: In my case, I want my consumer to listen to all queues. I have specified different functions in same consumer class for each type of message(Cancelconatct,Acceptcontact,....). So I need to run 2 instances of consumer class. Is there any way so that consumer can listen to all queues in channel?

Comment: you can have multiple consumers in the same instance/process. each call to "basic_consume" (or whatever "subscribe" method you are using) is a consumer. there's nothing wrong with that. but you need to create a consumer for each queue. there is not way to listen to all queues automatically.